# How to get rid of this seam on my texture?

Tags: texturing

[image]

On the side of the toe there is a change in color.

I don't know which texture it is. Whether its the normal map or the skin, I'm not sure. But when I go into texture paint mode, and select the blur tool, it barely changes when using it.

EDIT

I realized its the shape of the topology??? It goes all the way up the foot and cuts off at the front of the ankle in the shape of a seam formed by vertices on the foot

EDIT

It's also at the place where the map was separated into different sections. EG legs, arms etc

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to remove doubles

Comment: Hi, I don't think there were doubles because it didn't do anything :(

Comment: Anything else..?

Comment: It looks like you have doubles, try to move the vertices and see if they are connected or not

Comment: They are I swear

Comment: Can you upload the blend file? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Its in  the post now

Comment: Try to smooth it in sculpting

Comment: the normal map is causing this shading problem ( it's not in the file )

Comment: Its not in the render. Should I ignore it?

Comment: Wait yes it is...

Answer (score 3):

Things to check:

- **Creased?** Turn on the display of creases (<kbd>N</kbd> *> Mesh Display > Creases*), then enter *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and look for a blue line along that section. If you see the blue line, clear the crease (*Edge Select Mode*, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, *Clear Crease*)
- **Internal Face?** Check to see if you an internally extruded face along that section. Hit <kbd>Z</kbd> to enter *Wireframe Mode*, switch to *Face Select Mode*, and look for a third face attached to that edge. If so, delete it (them).
- **Edge Split?** Ensure you don't have an Edge-Split modifier with too low of a value (*Properties > Modifiers > Edge Split*)
- **Shade Flat?** Select all faces surrounding the issue and hit <kbd>W</kbd> then *Shade Smooth*

---

*I downloaded your blend and took a quick look.* It doesn't appear to be any of the things I've listed, but seem to be (as you suggested) associated with the UV mapped textures. The area in question is along two non-contiguous UV segments. So, unless the pixels directly under both segments have identical colors, one would absolutely expect there to be such a discontinuity.

*My suggestion is to re-project the geometry so as to avoid seams in your UV in prominent positions.*

Comment: If you are interested, here is a meta about the key markup: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/524/what-case-should-letters-inside-kbd-tags-be